# Adjust Image Size of Image to Parent View Size

Tags: swiftui

I just want to simply adjust the image size of image to the parent's view size.

Images in swiftUI are miss behaved children that simply will not adjust to their parent...
I wanna be able to call `ImageCard("image").frame(decide the size of the image)`

```swift
 struct ImageCard: View {
        let backgoundImage: String?
        var body: some View {
          ZStack{
            Image(backgoundImage!)
                .resizable() // for resizing
                .scaledToFit() // for filling image on ImageView
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3)
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly the intention was to fill proportionally, so

```
  ZStack{
    Image(backgoundImage!)
        .resizable() // for resizing
        .scaledToFill() // << here !! // for filling image on ImageView
```

but in that case it can spread out of bounds, so it needs to be clipped in place of `.frame` applied, so either

```
ImageCard("image")
   .frame(decide the size of the image)
   .clipped() // << here !!
```

or, better, as already described inject dimension inside card and apply it there, like

```
    Image(backgoundImage!)
        .resizable() // for resizing
        .scaledToFill()               // << here !!
        .frame(decide the size of the image)
        .clipped()                    // << here !!
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 3)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package just for jmages, You give it the max `height` & `width` without needing the `Image`'s exact dimensions & it'll maximize the size without being stretched: https://github.com/NoeOnJupiter/SImages

Usage:

```
DownsampledImage(.wrapped(UIImage(named: backgroundImage)))
    .resizable(.wrapped(true))
    .frame(width: width, height: height)
```

Plus this will `downsample` your image to the size it's displayed in, your memory usage will be much lower since it depends on the resolution of the `Image`.

Note: If you wanna bound the image to the whole `View`, use `UIScreen.main.bounds` for the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include two variables for `width` and `height` to make your `ImageCard()` become adjustable at any time since you mentioned that you wanted:

> ```
> I wanna be able to call ImageCard("image").frame(decide the size of the image)
> ```

You don't need `ZStack` or `scaleToFit()` because you wanted to decide the size whenever the `ImageCard()` is called. Code is below the image.

[image]

```
struct DemoView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ImageCard(backgroundImage: "Swift", width: 300, height: 500)
  }
}
struct ImageCard: View {
  let backgroundImage: String?
  let width: CGFloat
  let height: CGFloat
  var body: some View {
    Image(backgroundImage ?? "")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: width, height: height)
  }
}
```